# Worklight RuntimeMBeanCallable.call() exception

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, websphere-liberty

Ever since I merged my project from worklight 6.1 to 6.2 I have following error in my Eclipse Worklight Development Server log when deploying my application:

```
[ERROR   ] RuntimeMBeanCallable.call() exception
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
[INFO    ] Result: PrivateBanker: worklight///172.17.22.111: Rollback
[INFO    ] SRVE0242I: [PrivateBanker] [/PrivateBanker] [PreviewServlet]: Initialization successful.
```

In my worklight console, I find the following:

```
[2014-07-08 11:02:30]             Starting build process: application 'PrivateBanker', all environments 
[2014-07-08 11:02:50]             Project 'PrivateBankerPrivateBankerAndroid' was imported. 
[2014-07-08 11:02:50]             Application 'PrivateBanker' with all environments build finished.
[2014-07-08 11:02:50]             Deploying application 'PrivateBanker' with all environments to Worklight Server... 
[2014-07-08 11:03:16]             Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server: UndeclaredThrowableException
```

Does anyone know what it means and what the concequences are?
At first sight the application looks correctly deployed, since I can access it in the browser simulator.

I tried recreating my project from scratch, by just copying my html and js files, but the error remains. The error doesn't appear when I remove my Android environment.

I don't know if it's related, but I also noticed following warnings in the log.

```
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.QueryParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.CookieParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.PathParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.core.Context annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.MatrixParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The warnings are not related. If you can provide your project we'll run it here and see what this is about.

Comment: Ok, what is the best way to provide it?

Comment: You can upload it to Dropbox.

Comment: Ok, I found the issue.
In the application I use a large (20MB) json file with pdfs.
This json file is under apps\MyProject\common\data. I can deploy my project without any issues, once I remove this file.

Comment: Can anyone explain how this results in the exception I had? I tried to simulate this problem in a new HelloWorld project, but here I got an out of memory exception. Which makes a lot more sense then the UndeclaredThrowableException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, this is a known issue in Worklight 6.2; if you are an IBM Worklight customer or business partner you can open a PMR (with a link to this question) so that once this issue is fixed, an iFix will be provided to you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
I'll create a PMR once I get our account information.

Comment: PMR 49633.800.624 was created

Comment: What is the status of this issue? I am still seeing the error when trying to build on version 6.2.0.00-20140922-2259.

Comment: If it is not resolved for you, you can open a PMR for your company and mention the PMR above by Hans.